# How to dynamically generate HTML?

Tags: html

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to make a basic webpage that displays a list (like a restaurant menu). Desired result:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Restaurant menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Except that these items are stored locally as a .txt file, and are subject to change so I don't want to copy paste them to the html every single time.

Comment: A reminder to you all. Do not downvote because the question is basic. Downvote if the question is not clear, badly formatted or shows no research effort. None of the three apply. Vote as duplicate and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a server side language like PHP, or whatever you are familiar with or would like to learn. For example with PHP...

The text file:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

Your page, lets call it list.php

```
<?php 
      // reads the lines of menu.txt into an array
      $menu = file('menu.txt'); 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Restaurant menu</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if(!empty($menu)): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($menu as $item): ?>
          <li><?php echo $item ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php else: ?>
       <p>No items.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

You could use Javascript to do this. The problem there is that if for some godforsaken reason the user has javascript disabled, or if they dont have a browser that can run javascript, then you cant even view the content. So really, serverside language should be used for this.

Also, please dont just cut and paste this code. There are a great many things not accounted for, and it will probably lead to issues. You can use it as a starting point, but youll really want to familiarize yourself with the language and then perhaps post more specific questions about how to parse the format of the file, or what format you should use, error handling, and other things.

Comment: I am very comfortable with Python, and I've heard of something called Django. Is that applicable to this situation?

Comment: Python would be fine for this, though you want to keep in mind where the site will be deployed to and if the server will support python. Django is a great framework IMO, but depending on the overall requirements it could be overkill. If this is all you need to do you can probably get away with this one page being a python script. If the site as a whole requires more dyanmic processing then Django would probably be good choice. That said, if you havent done web dev before with python or Django, youve got a lot of learning to do :-)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I dont think that is definitely necessary. Its defineitly the better route, but learning a framework as you learn a language and/or as it is applied to webdev isnt necessarily a non-starter. I was more or less 1 step above beginner with PHP when i picked up Symfony 0.6 and I think working withing that framework taught me more about PHP and good development with it than cobbling together my own one-off system ever did. (id done maybe 10 - 20 sites in php before that).

Comment: @prodigitalson: I got burned not once nor twice by working with people who learned a framework/library without learning the basics of the language. jQuery and CodeIgniter are the most prominent offenders. No more.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Oh jQuery for sure. There are a lot of people out there that "know" JS which only applies to jQuery and even then not particularly good jQuery usage. I could see the same with CI I think. I think the most important thing though is for the person to use the framework as a teacher of concepts, and then to "backtrace" those down to the language level. I agree not everyone does this, but its how I worked a lot of things out, and I'm pretty much at home in the PHP world with anything you can throw at me, though i won't always accept the project :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your options are a server side language (PHP, .NET) or a Javascript call to server-side code.

Plain HTML won't cut it for what you need to do.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a web language like PHP, JavaScript or many of the other ones. 
HTML code is static, and does not change.

I'd recommend looking at jQuery for quick and simple dynamic pages.